# UnboundLocalError: Local variable 'user' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

This is part of a code that runs a moderator bot in a chatroom i use. This section of the code is to approve someone's request to cam up but whenever I use the command I get this unbound local error...
I have gone through this so many times and I can't figure out why I'm getting it.

```
def approveCam(room, identifier):
    if not room.bpass:
        return

    if type(identifier) in [str, unicode, int]:
        user = room._getUser(identifier)
        if not user:
            return "User " + str(identifier) + " was not found..."

    if user.broadcasting:
        return

    room._sendCommand("privmsg", [room._encodeMessage("/allowbroadcast " + room.bpass),
    "#0,en" + "n" + str(user.id) + "-" + user.nick])
```

The problem seems to be at "if user.broadcasting:"

the code worked on a previous version of the bot like this

```
def approveCam(room, user):
    if type(user) is str or type(user) is unicode:
        nick = user
        user = room._getUser(user)
    if not user:
        return "User "+nick+" was not found..."

    if not room.bpass:
        return

    room._sendCommand("privmsg", [room._encodeMessage("/allowbroadcast "+room.bpass),
    "#0,en"+"n"+ user.id+"-"+user.nick])
```

and here is the response i get in command prompt when i try to run the command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Ejah\Downloads\Desktop\Tunebot-Master\tinychat.py", line     1262
in onMessage
  SETTINGS['onMessageExtend'](self, user, msg)
 File "tunebot.py", line 1316, in onMessageExtended
  handleUserCommand(room, user, msg)
 File "tunebot.py", line 1722, in handleUserCommand
  res = botterCommands(room, userCmd, userArgsStr, userArgs, target,
 File "tunebot.py", line 2786, in botterCommands
  res = approveCam(room, user)
 File "tunebot.py", line 4043, in approveCam
  if user.broadcasting:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user' referenced before assignment"
```

Comment: If your second `if` statement is False (where you comparing `identifier`) you'll not assign to `user` anything. So it is not existed

Comment: please indent your code correctly

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to raise an error when `identifier` is of an invalid type and all will become clear:

```
def approveCam(room, identifier):
    if not room.bpass:
        return

    if type(identifier) in [str, unicode, int]:
        user = room._getUser(identifier)
        if not user:
            return "User " + str(identifier) + " was not found..."
    else:
        raise ValueError('Invalid type for identifier')

    if user.broadcasting:
        return

    room._sendCommand("privmsg", [room._encodeMessage("/allowbroadcast " + room.bpass),
        "#0,en" + "n" + str(user.id) + "-" + user.nick])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user.broadcasting - This is not correct
```

At this point user does not exist and hence the interpreter won't allow that. You must initialise local variables before using them.

Make user a global variable with some value to it.

Comment: I thought it was initialized though this has to be such a simple thing i'm not getting

Comment: Use globals is a bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably `if type(identifier) in [str, unicode, int]:` is `False`, so the body of the `if` is not executed and `user` is never inizialized.

Initialize `user` before the second `if` if possible, or rethink your code.

P.S. Don't use getter and setter! Python is not Java, if you really need to use them, use a property instead.

Comment: Don't move `user = room._getUser(identifier)` before the `if` statement. The type checking is there for a reason! If `identifier` is of an invalid type, `getUser` will error out.

Comment: hmm.. i'm still confused, i'm trying really hard here to understand

Comment: Is the body of `if type(identifier) in [str, unicode, int]:` executed? If the answer is no, then in `if user.broadcasting:` you are trying to use an empty variable.

Comment: but shouldn't the (identifier) being user be executing that variable?